# Laravel Error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 ()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone

I'm having a little challenge; not sure where the error is coming from but your guidance would be hugely appreciated.

I am using dropzone plugin to upload an image but each time I upload I get this on my console "[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 () (mentee-upload-image, line 0)". Below are my codes.

HTML

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                 @csrf
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$profile->id}}">
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <!--File upload 3-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="image">Upload your Profile Picture.</label>
                                        <a class="dropzone-attach-files btn btn-sm mb-0">Attach files</a>
                                        <div class="d-none" id="fileUpload3" action="{{url('mentee-upload-image')}}" class="dropzone">
                                            <div class="fallback">
                                                <input name="photo" type="file" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Preview -->
                                        <div class="mt-3" id="formFiles3"></div>
                                        <!-- File preview template -->
                                        <div class="d-none" id="formTemplate3">
                                            <div class="card mb-3">
                                                <div class="p-2">
                                                    <div class="row align-items-start">
                                                        <div class="col-auto">
                                                            <img data-dz-thumbnail src="#" class="avatar border rounded">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col pl-0">
                                                            <a href="#" class="text-muted font-weight-bold" data-dz-name></a>
                                                            <p class="mb-0"><small data-dz-size></small> <small class="d-block text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></small></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-auto pt-2">
                                                            <a class="btn-lg text-danger" href="#" data-dz-remove><i class="icon-trash-2"></i></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end: File preview template -->
                                        <small id="dropzoneHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Max file size is 5MB.</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--end: File upload 3-->
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

JS

```
  <script>
   Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    //Form 3
    var form3 = $('#fileUpload3');
    form3.dropzone({
        url: "{{url('mentee-upload-image')}}",
        method: "POST",
        maxFilesize: 5,
        maxFiles: 1,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        previewsContainer: "#formFiles3",
        previewTemplate: $("#formTemplate3").html(),
        clickable: ".dropzone-attach-files"
    });
</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
  public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    
    $filepath =  "";
    $fileName ="";
    $mimetype='';
    if($file){
         $destinationPath = 'mentees/';
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
        $fileName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $request->input('firstname').'_'. $request->input('lastname')).rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
        $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        }
    
    $menteep = Mentee::find($request->input('id'));
    if($fileName){
        $menteep->photo = $fileName;
    }
    $menteep->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Profile picture updated successfully.');
}
```

I would really appreciate any advice and support provided here.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing that what you do inside your dropzone plugin is a POST request to a url of your image.
To make POST requests, you need to add the CSRF token inside your request data.

You may have to do something like this:

```js
     ...,
     params: function params(files, xhr, chunk) { 
           return { 
                  '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
           };
     },
```